# Difference between SQL Server Standard and Enterprise Edition 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

We are working on a project migration from SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2012. When we contacted the customer they have asked us to list us the advanced features in SQL Server 2012. The customer system is in Enterprise Edition. But the development environment is in Standard Edition.

When we were trying to apply many new features like Columnstore Index, it says this can be applied only on Enterprise Edition. Can you please help me to list out such features in SQL Server 2012?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/microsoft-sql-server/9780133408539/ch01lev2sec16.html  -- you'll probably just want to google around, that's all any of us are going to do

Comment: Any reason you don't use, well, the Developer Edition for development, which offers the same feature set as Enterprise? The restriction being that you're not allowed to use it when you're actually going into production, of course. Only if you're concerned about ultimately deploying your solution to an environment which will only have Standard is this worth worrying about. (Also, while columnstores *were* introduced in 2012, they come with so many restrictions compared to later editions that I'm not sure you want to list this as a selling point.)

Comment: While off-topic for SO, you can have a look [here](http://www.midnightdba.com/Jen/2014/03/the-case-for-sql-server-2012-enterprise-vs-standard-edition/) (first google result).

Comment: I think the official documentation for 2012 is gone, however, 2014's is still about and i don't believe anything really changed (2014 mainly added azure functionality): [Features Supported by the Editions of SQL Server 2014](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/getting-started/features-supported-by-the-editions-of-sql-server-2014?view=sql-server-2014). @JeroenMostert raises a good concern though, your dev environment should really use the developer edition. if you're "upgrading" though, why only to 2012?

Comment: @Krish why are you migrating to an *unsupported* edition, and why *downgrade* to Standard? In fresh versions (2017, 2016 SP1) the programmability differences between editions are small: even Express has partitioning, columnstores, in-memory tables etc. The Developer edition is free and has the same features as the Enterprise edition

Comment: @Krish the customer *can't* buy SQL Server 2012 btw, since it's not supported. If you care about the edition differences of available versions, check the [Editions and supported features of SQL Server 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-2017) and [Editions and supported features of SQL Server 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2017?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos We have informed the same with them as well. But since there is an extended support for the SQL 2012, customer wanted to go with it. By the way they already have the server as well.

Comment: @Krish that is a discussion for your project managers, not SO. Did they *really* sign a downgrade contract? What does the customer care about *columnstores*? Are they aware that they'll lose online backup, indexing operations? Forget about high availabitlity? Anyway, the list of features is available in MSDN and SQL Server's Books online

Comment: @Krish check [Features Supported by the Editions of SQL Server 2012](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/cc645993(v=sql.110)) for the full feature list.

Comment: Have you tried Google???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This page](http://www.midnightdba.com/Jen/2014/03/the-case-for-sql-server-2012-enterprise-vs-standard-edition/) is a really good breakdown of the key differences between Standard and Enterprise editions.  Also, rather than using Standard Edition, use the Developer Edition to develop in - it's free to use, and contains the same features as Enterprise Edition.